# Flutter Navigator returning black corners

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator

I'm developing a simple todo app. On my first screen, I called a Navigator.pop(context) to return the next screen. The functionality of the second screen is working perfectly but I have black sides. Are there any solutions for this issue? [image: First Screen][image: Second Screen]

Comment: You mean your dialog has a shadow behind it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53848301/11623001

This link has answer to your question.